# PHP Encoding (Guess UTF-8)

Tags: php, mysql, database, encoding, utf-8

I'm programming a system so an user can edit what he posts. Simplified it's a textarea/input field which stores in a database and a page that retrieves it. The problem is, I think the encoding isn't okay, because strings are stored in the database like "Ã©" or something (phpmyadmin view).

Insert page:

1. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
2. I insert `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['field']);`

Output page:

1. Object from database.
2. `htmlspecialchars($object->field);`

But expected is:
Output page:

1. Object from database.
2. `htmlentities($object->field);`, right?

Why isn't the data stored in MySql properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your database encoding is set to utf-8, you need to set the tranfer encoding to utf-8, too. To do that you have to query

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

before inserting into the table.

Comment: +1 This is necessary to see the correct encoding in phpMyAdmin. However, it is usually not necessary to get the same out of the DB that has been put in.

Comment: That is true Andre, but if you connect to the database using the wrong character set then you may actually be storing mis-encoded data in the database table. This is obviously undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Is the database *connection* UTF-8 ? Bear in mind, that's not the default encoding, you have to explicitly set it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell htmlentities that you feed it UTF-8:

```
htmlentities($text, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

Otherwise it assumes it gets ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Maybe i'm looking for something different, because i've placed something in the database ("Testé"), and it's displayed okay with htmlentities($text); How can I insert "Testé" correctly without the help of phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

This site http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet should give you an idea of whats needed for UTF-8 in PHP and MySQL.

Oh and dont forget to use these after connecting to your DB:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```